# Can't parse basic JSON - iOS

Tags: ios, json, cocoa-touch, parsing, facebook-graph-api

I have an iOS application which downloads and parses a JSON file from the Facebook API.

However, whenever I try to parse it my app crashes and I get this error:

```
2013-11-06 15:31:41.473 JSONTESTER[10881:70b] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized 
selector sent to instance 0x10d01bd30
2013-11-06 15:31:41.476 JSONTESTER[10881:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10d01bd30'
```

Here is the simple JSON file I am trying to parse:

```
{


"id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
   "name": "Dan Sadjadian",
   "home": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "from": {
               "name": "Jane Smith",
               "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "message": "deadline is only 16 days!!! Where are you guys!!!!!!!!! Please shall we start!!!!!",
            "actions": [
               {
                  "name": "Comment",
                  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxx/posts/xxxxxxxxxxx"
               },
               {
                  "name": "Like",
                  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx/posts/xxxxxxxxxxxx"
               }
            ],
            "privacy": {
               "value": ""
            },
            "type": "status",
            "status_type": "mobile_status_update",
            "created_time": "2013-11-06T14:40:23+0000",
            "updated_time": "2013-11-06T14:40:23+0000"
         },
       ],
     },
}
```

Here is my code which should work....

```
cell.username.text = [[[[[facebook_array objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"from"] valueForKey:@"name"];
```

As you can see I am trying to get access to "name" which is in "from" which is in the "data" array which is in "home".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: More than likely it's the second objectAtIndex:. You should break that line of code down to find out which one is the culprit. The data object is not a value it is an array which would make it an object or technically speaking a collection. [ array ] { dictionary }

Comment: You don't show how you get Facebook_array. You should log the class of facebook_array to see if it's really an array (it looks like a dictionary, if that's what you've posted in your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think the first step is to select `home` object not `[index]`.**

given your json file above.

You are doing `[index].data.[0].from.name`

Your data look like `home.data.[0].from.name`

On linux/gnustep this is how I get the `home.data.[0].from.name` property, I saved your example as `fb.json` as above:

```
NSError * error;

NSData * jsdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"fb.json"];
id jsDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsdata
                                            options:0
                                              error:&error];
// not: data.from.name
// but: home.data.from.name
NSDictionary * home = [jsDict objectForKey:@"home"];
NSArray * data = [home objectForKey:@"data"];
NSDictionary * firstObj = [data objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary * from = [firstObj objectForKey:@"from"];
NSString * name = [from objectForKey:@"name"];

NSLog( @"%@", name);
```

output:

```
 Jane Smith
```

If the whole json object from the example is in array in the actual data from fb then you would start with `[index]` but still the next needs to be selecting `home`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
NSArray *arrData=[MAIN_DICTIONARY objectForKey:@"data"];

NSDictionary *data=[arrData objectForIndex:0];

NSDictionary *from=[data objectForKey:@"from"];

NSLog(@"Name = %@", [from objectForKey:@"name"]);
```

I hope it helps you to understand how it works.

Comment: This approach is the best way to debug this kind of thing. Always break up compound statements first.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary classes don't have objectAtIndex method. It's from NSArray. And I guess that you can move through JSON only using objectForKey.